# Is there another way to create an ViewModelFactory in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-mvvm

I'm just start learning Java and Android and I have worry about the warning displayed in Build console of Android Studio 4.0 and Gradle plugin 3.6.3.

For my understanding, this warning seems to be important.
He can cause the problems with execution of code ?
How can I solve it ?
Is there another way to create an ViewModelFactory in Android ?

This is the warning:

```
\ViewModelFactory.java:29: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            return (T) new MainViewModel(mProjectRepository,mTaskRepository,mExecutor);
                       ^
  required: T
  found:    MainViewModel
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends ViewModel declared in method <T>create(Class<T>)
```

And here the ViewModelFactory:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.cleanup.todoc.repositories.ProjectRepository;
import com.cleanup.todoc.repositories.TaskRepository;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

public class ViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final ProjectRepository mProjectRepository;
    private final TaskRepository mTaskRepository;
    private final Executor mExecutor;

    public ViewModelFactory(ProjectRepository projectRepository, TaskRepository taskRepository, Executor executor) {
        mProjectRepository = projectRepository;
        mTaskRepository = taskRepository;
        mExecutor = executor;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked cast")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new MainViewModel(mProjectRepository,mTaskRepository,mExecutor);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for each tip and the help to understand the the problem.

Comment: "He can cause the problems with execution of code ?" -- no, your code will run correctly.

Comment: Thank You CommonsWare. If it is no danger then, what is the purpose of warnings ?

Comment: The warnings are because the compiler is nervous that you might be making a mistake. And, in truth, if you tried using this factory to create a viewmodel *other* than `MainViewModel`, it *would* be a mistake. Frequently, though, we do not create these factories ourselves. Instead, we use dependency inversion frameworks (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.).

Comment: OK. I think I understand that now: When I _touch_ the "border line" then compiler tells me "Warning". And if I _cross_ the "border line" then compiler tells me "Error".

Comment: But, still. If someone have another way to create an viewmodelfactory I'm very interested to see it.